# Is there an alternative to the `.each` method for single selection?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps

I have the following pulling info from my db.

```
function start(){
  $.get("map_process.php", function (data){
    $(data).find("marker").each(function (){
     var name = $(this).attr('name');
     var verified = $(this).attr('verification');
     + others...
)};
)};
}
```

Eventually these used to create markers for a google map. This works fine and create markers for each of the entries in the db, however I need to be able to 'update' only one column's value when other functions are executed. I'm pretty sure I have this process correct, however I just don't know what I can do to just get values for **one** entry and not for **each**. Is there anyway I can do this? - like replacing `.each` with something else relating to just one entry?

Comment: `var name = $(data).find("marker").eq(0).attr('name')` etc

Comment: how are you planning to specify your marker ? through index or attribute ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek Ideally, I would rather attribute because the index's have the potential to change with deletion.

Comment: @adeneo Is there a way I can do this by another identifier within the table than just `.eq(x)`

Comment: Sure, there's a number of ways to do that, but it's not easy to answer without knowing what identifier specifically you want to use ?

Comment: @adeneo, same person had to change accounts because of computer troubles. I know what identifier I want to use, however this identifier is not just the position within the table. I want to be able to identify by a particular value within the table - eg. the key.I was looking at `.has() and `.filter` methods but am not having any luck

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use jquery [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to select specific element, like below:

```
$(data).find("marker").index(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is to find marker with specified attribute :

```
$(data).find("marker[name='your name']")
```

this will select a marker with specified name.

source :

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: is it possible to use this with a variable instead of `'your name'`?

Comment: @user3663720 ofcourse just use $(data).find("marker[name="+variable name+"]")